# base extension of algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

Let $\bf{G}$ be a simple and simply connected algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it true that the base extension of $\bf{G}$ over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$, i.e., ${\bf G}\times_{\mathrm{Spec(\mathbb{Z})}}\mathrm{Spec}(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, is simple and simply connected for all but finitely many p?

Comment: What does it mean to be simple and simply connected for a group defined over Z? Is it just that its generic fibre is simple and simply connected? If so then the fibre at a prime p might not even be a reductive algebraic group (it could be non-reduced etc).

Comment: @eric: I mean it is defined over Z like SL_n. I don't think this should be true for all p, but I think should be true for all big enough p.

Comment: So what do you mean by simple and simply connected? These words only apply to reductive groups, as far as I know, but I am unclear whether your group is reductive in the sense of SGA or whether it's just its generic fibre is. The answer to your question depends on this.

Comment: For instance SL_n is simple algebraic group over C.

Comment: I know. My question is what is the definition of "simply and simply connected" for a group defined over Z.

Comment: I am simply asking that SL_n is simple and simply connect over C and it is defined over Z. This group can also be considered over algebraic closure of a finite field which is again simple and simply connected. I am trying to understand this point

Comment: The problem is that SL_n has many models over Z, and for one of them your question is true and for others it is false. A group over Z is not determined by its generic fiber. Even though you don't seem to be able to make your question precise, the answer to the question I think you're asking is that for general p the group might not even be reductive let alone simple and simply connected, but if your group has good reduction at p then the associated based root data will not change and hence it will remain simple and simply connected.

Comment: @Eric: I have edited the question.

Comment: The problem is that to reduce a scheme defnied over Q, mod p, you need to choose a model over Z, and there are usually infinitely many. That's the problem with the question.

Comment: @Eric: Pick your favorite model.

Comment: There is no favourite model, but all models will have the property that they have good reduction outside a finite set of primes. You seem to not really appreciate the subtleties of what is going on here, but the answer to your modified question is "yes, whatever model you choose".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the "reasonable" interpretation of your question is "yes". The real point is that the property of being "simply connected" in the sense of connected semisimple groups is characterized in terms of the root datum of the geometric fiber, and there is a "local constancy" property for root data in the setting of reductive group schemes over any ring, ultimately based on considerations with tori and Lie algebras over rings.

(**Warning**: "simply connected" for connected semisimple groups in positive characteristic has *nothing* to do with the triviality of the etale fundamental group, as the latter is *always* nontrivial for smooth affine varieties of positive dimension in positive characteristic.  Rather, it is defined in terms of the absence of nontrivial central isogenous covers by other connected semisimple groups, and is very easy to verify for SL$_n$ directly. It happens to be equivalent to triviality of the etale fundamental group in characteristic 0, but that is an entirely separate matter of no logical relevance to the question about properties in positive characteristic.)

The discussion addresses this from a broader perspective. If all you are interested in is SL$_n$ or any other "simply connected classical group" then nothing below is needed: all of the "classical groups" can be treated directly over any algebraically closed field on its own terms by directly checking that the coroots span the cocharacter lattice of a maximal torus, from which "simply connected" is immediate via how it is *defined* in a characteristic-free manner.  Likewise for being "simple": it is a standard exercise for the classical groups, and is also characterized by irreducibility of the root system (which can be computed in each classical case).

Now for the general perspective. 
By easy "denominator-chasing" stuff, if $A$ is a domain with fraction field $K$ and $G$ is an affine $K$-group scheme of finite type then there exists a nonzero $a \in A$ and an affine $A[1/a]$-group scheme $\mathbf{G}$ of finite type with generic fiber $G$.  Much more serious is that for a suitable nonzero multiple $a'$ of $a$ in $A$ (i.e., passing to a dense open subscheme ${\rm{Spec}}(A[1/a'])$ of ${\rm{Spec}}(A[1/a])$) various properties of the generic fiber as a $K$-scheme are satisfied by $\mathbf{G}_{A[1/a']} \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(A[1/a'])$.

Among such properties are "geometrically connected fibers" [EGA IV$_3$, 9.7.7(ii)] (this is not obvious, as it is *false* for merely "connected fibers", but a connected scheme with a rational point over a field is automatically geometrically connected -- a simple exercise in the finite type case which is all you need, and [EGA IV$_2$, 4.5.14] in general), flatness [EGA IV$_3$, 11.2.6.1(ii)] (though for your situation over a Dedekind domain this much is trival since flat = torsion-free over a Dedekind base), and even smoothness (by tracking the Jacobian condition and fiber dimension in the presence of flatness, or by [EGA IV$_4$, 17.7.8(ii)]).  Actually, it is a general (not obvious) fact that a smooth relatively affine group scheme over an irreducible scheme has all fibers connected if the generic fiber is connected, but this is not needed and so we will pass over it in silence.

So by such general result (or hand-waving), it is "standard" upon that $G$ extends to a smooth affine $A[1/a]$-scheme $\mathbf{G}$ with (geometrically) connected fibers for some nonzero $a \in A$. With $A = \mathbf{Z}$ this says for any smooth connected affine $\mathbf{Q}$-group $G$ there exists a nonzero integer $N$ such that $G$ is the generic fiber of a smooth affine $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$-group $\mathbf{G}$ such that $\mathbf{G}_{\mathbf{F}_p}$ is (geometrically) connected all all $p \nmid N$.

Now comes the real content: if $G$ is reductive (resp. semisimple, resp. semisimple and simply connected) then does the same hold for $\mathbf{G}_{\mathbf{F}_p}$ for all but finitely many $p \nmid N$?  This has no number-theoretic content at all, as it is really an assertion about group schemes over arbitrary domains: if $G$ is a smooth affine group scheme over a domain $A$ with fraction field $K$ such that all fibers are connected and if $G_K$ is reductive (resp. semisimple, resp. semisimple and simply connected) then does the same hold for the fibers $G_s$ over points $s$ in some dense open subscheme $U \subset {\rm{Spec}}(A)$?  The answer is affirmative (and has nothing whatsoever to do with any classification theory for reductive or semisimple groups over fields, nor anything to do with the existence of Chevalley groups): for reductivity as well as for semisimplicity these are part of [SGA3, XIX, 2.6], and are also proved as Prop. 3.1.9(1) in the article "Reductive group schemes" in "Autour des schemas en groupes", no. 42-43 of Panoramas en Syntheses, SMF. One could instead make arguments via classification theorems and Chevalley groups. Choose your own poison.

Once that is done, and we arrange that $G$ is reductive over $A$, all geometric fibers have the *same* root datum (so if one fiber is simply connected then so are all fibers).  This is elementary: we pick a maximal $K$-torus $T_{\eta} \subset G_K$ and a finite extension $K'/K$ such that $(T_{\eta})_{K'}$ is split. Then by replacing $A$ with some $A[1/a]$ we can find a domain $A' \subset K'$ finite flat over $A$ such that (i) $K' = {\rm{Frac}}(A')$ and (ii) $(T_{\eta})_{K'}$ "spreads out" to a closed $A'$-subgroup $T' \subset G_{A'}$ that is a split fiberwise maximal torus in $G_{A'}$. Since ${\rm{Spec}}(A') \rightarrow {\rm{Spec}}(A)$ is surjective, we can rename $A'$ as $A$ so that $G$ contains a closed $A$-subgroup $T$ which is a split fiberwise maximal torus. By localizing a bit more on $A$, the action of $T$ on ${\rm{Lie}}(G)$ then decomposes into a direct sum of ${\rm{Lie}}(T)$ and free modules of rank 1 on which $T$ acts through a fiberwise nontrivial character.  In a similar manner we get the coroots as cocharacters of $T$ over $A$ (localizing a bit more on $A$, though that isn't really necessary) by using the intrinsic characterization of coroots. So this builds a root datum using the character and cocharacter groups of the split $A$-torus $T$, and as such identifies the root data of all fibers. Since "simple" for a connected semisimple group over an algebraically closed field is characterized by irreducibility of the root system, that property also spreads out from the geometric generic fiber.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: but let me first confess that I don't know really much about algebraic geometry beside some basic facts. Let me ask my question in the most simple way. Let G be a simple and simply connected over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $G$ be defined over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then one can consider $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$ points of G, namely $G(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ and so one obtains an algebraic groups over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p$. I am asking if $G(\bar{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ is simple and simply connected for all but finitely many $p$.

Comment: The answer is "yes": for any Hopf algebra finitely generated over $\mathbf{Z}$ that gives $G$ over $\mathbf{C}$, for all but finitely many $p$ the associated group over $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_p$ is connected semisimple if $G$ is connected semisimple, and likewise for "simple" as well as "simply connected".  The natural proof is via "algebraic groups" over rings such as $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$.  Amusingly, Grothendieck developed SGA3 to give the "right" proof that ${\rm{SL}}_n(\mathbf{Z}) \rightarrow {\rm{SL}}_n(\mathbf{F}_p)$ is surjective for all $p$; mild overkill. :)

Comment: Dear nfdc23: I am really thankful for your answer and comments. Since I don't have any algebraic geometer around myself, let me ask another question. For me the Chevalley group over an arbitrary field $K$, as is explained in Steinberg's book, is the base extension of the Chevalley groups over $\mathbb{C}$ to the field $K$. Is it correct to say this? If it it is correct then can I deduce my question from Theorem 6, page 58 of Steinberg book available at http://math.ucla.edu/~rst/YaleNotes.pdf

Comment: Yes, but you need Theorem 6 and page 60 culminating in the "Existence Theorem" there to get roots and character lattice to match up. For each rank-$n$ root system, there is a *unique* "smooth" affine group over $\mathbf{Z}$ containing ${\rm{GL}}_1^n$ as a closed $\mathbf{Z}$-subgroup that is a fiberwise maximal torus with each fiber connected semisimple and simply connected.  This is a big theorem in SGA3. It gives an intrinsic characterization of Steinberg's construction over $\mathbf{Z}$. I am as allergic to Steinberg's technique as you are to Grothendieck's, so I cannot say more. Sorry!

Comment: @M.B., note that you cannot base change directly from $\mathbb C$ to an *arbitrary* field $K$ (particularly not one of positive characteristic!).  The big idea of Chevalley groups is to *produce* a 'canonical' *integral* model for each split, simple algebraic group over $\mathbb C$; and you *can* base change *that model* from $\mathbb Z$ to any field (but a different model might have given you a different base change).